# Stata: label variables using forvalue loop

Tags: stata

I am trying to label a batch of variables using a loop as follows, but failed with stata error  "invalid syntax". I couldn't find out where went wrong.

```
local myvars "basicenumerator" "basicfr_gpslatitude" "basicfr_gpslongitude" 

local mylabels "Name of enumerator" "the latitude of the farmers house" "the longtitude of the farmers house" 

local n : word count `mylabels'

forvalues i = 1/`n'{
    local a: word `i' of `mylabels'
    local b: word `i' of `myvars'
    label var `b' "`a'"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this, the main trick is to get Stata to show you what it thinks the local macros are. This script makes your code reproducible and also fixes it.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen basicenumerator = 42 
gen basicfr_gpslatitude = 42 
gen basicfr_gpslongitude = 42 

local myvars `" "basicenumerator" "basicfr_gpslatitude" "basicfr_gpslongitude" "' 

local mylabels `" "Name of enumerator" "the latitude of the farmers house" "the longtitude of the farmers house" "' 

local n : word count `mylabels'

mac li 

forvalues i = 1/`n'{
    local a: word `i' of `mylabels'
    local b: word `i' of `myvars'
    label var `b' "`a'"
}
```

The problem is that the outer `" "` get stripped in defining your locals, so to keep the `" "` as desired, you need to wrap each string within compound double quotes.

For explanation, see http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u12.pdf 12.4.6.

Picky correction: spelling is *longitude*.